# How to avoid URL $_GET variables after submitting a form with ajax?

Tags: php, forms, url, get

```
<form id='gbookform'>
    <input id='inputname' type='text' name='name' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Your name'>
    <input id='inputcon' type='text' name='contact' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Your contact or website'>
    <div id='forminfo'></div>
    <textarea id='inputstory' name='story' rows='9' placeholder='Your story'></textarea>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfobygTAAAAACxBzCl1FxPe4lALE-669wt6NC7G"></div>
    <input id='btnsubmit' type='submit' value='SEND'>
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#gbookform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gbookajax.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#dataload').load('gbookdata.php');
            $('#forminfo').text(data).show();
        }
    })
})
```

After submitting the form I see my variables written inside url:
`http://localhost/gbook.php?name=q&contact=q&story=q&g-recaptcha-response=`

How can I avoid this ?

Comment: Have you tried, to not serialize? I submit my data someway like this:
data: { 
        'foo': 'bar', 
        'foobar':'barfoo'
    },

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with your ajax. Have you put the JS bit inside of a `$(document).ready` function?

Comment: you're looking at wrong ajax call. Nothing wrong with your ajax call. check again

Comment: How you scoop your js code ? external script or inline script , wanna see full code !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify the form method :

```
<form id='gbookform' method='post'>...</form>
```

Comment: This isn't correct, he is trying to using ajax to submit the form.

Comment: Isn't the form still sent, once the AJAX call is made ?

Comment: No since the default action is disabled.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` will stop that

Comment: Right, missed this line, sorry. Seems like it's an JS/AJAX problem, as @Andrew mentioned in his comment on the question, my best guess would be that the JS bit isn't executed.

Comment: (Technically, though, my answer is correct, if `method='post'` is added, the `$_GET` variables will no longer be used :P)

Comment: Your answer only works because OP is misunderstanding that only a symptom has been fixed, but the cause (i.e. his JS / AJAX) is still broken.

Comment: @JonStirling, what would be your solution ?

Comment: @bonaca My "solution" would be to find out why your javascript AJAX request doesn't appear to be firing. For that, there a couple of relevant questions in the comments in your question :)

Comment: @bonaca Of course if you're not actually bothered about being redirected then you could just remove that JS all together.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will accept `roberto06`'s solution because this is only working solution at this moment, and continue to explore all others.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax is not working. the file name in

`http://localhost/gbook.php?name=q&contact=q&story=q&g-recaptcha-response=`

is different from

`url: "gbookajax.php",`

so i believe the form is being posted the regular way, and not the ajax. 
what you can do is put

```
$("#btnsubmit").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gbookajax.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#dataload').load('gbookdata.php');
            $('#forminfo').text(data).show();
        }
    })
})
```

in a function, like:

```
function postForm(){
    ...// the ajax request above
}
```

and add replace:

`<input id='btnsubmit' type='submit' value='SEND'>`

with

`<button onclick="postForm()">SEND</button>`

Comment: That would be the equivalent of putting a plaster on after cutting off a finger. He would be better off finding out why his function isn't being called so he doesn't run into this issue everywhere.

Comment: Ajax is working fine. The only problem is url containing variables.

Comment: then how do you explain the difference in urls? if this ajax was fired(only) then you'd see the url as `http://localhost/gbookajax.php`(because vars would be in body) .not `gbook.php`. besides i already found out the problem with your code. i'm updating my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you want to send form as GET, but suppress the variables that show in your link, or if you want to send a POST request. According to the JS you provided I assumed you want to send a POST request so I think this should work for you.

```
<form id='gbookform' method="post">
...
</form>
```

Notice the difference in the first line of code, where method is added.
Default method for form is GET, hence why it was treated as such.

// EDIT
Since you are trying to send a post request, you should also suppress the buttons core functionality to send the request and refresh the page. So to your JS you should probably add this...

```
$("#gbookform").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "gbookajax.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        $('#dataload').load('gbookdata.php');
        $('#forminfo').text(data).show();
    }
})
return false;

})
```